# Angular Auxillary Routes to named outlets inside MatDialog

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, router-outlet

After going through a few related questions and Issues from GitHub, I am even more confused.

**Problem:** I have a secondary module which I want to be routed via it's own routing module inside a MatDialog that contains a named router outlet.

**What I have done:** So far I am successful in calling the root of the second module but I cannot call any of the child routes of the second module. It always gives an error that route is not found/defined.

I have defined all the child routes with an outlet name but it gives the same error.

I am using router navigator like this:

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: {atd: ['add-task']}}], {skipLocationChange: true});
```

`add-task` being the Parent Route of the second module.

But if i call the following inside a component of the second module:

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: {'atd': ["add-task", "sales"]}}], {skipLocationChange: true});
```

I get the following error:

```
error: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'add-task/sales'
```

And yes I have the route `add-task/sales` in my routing module.

Any ideas as regarding how to solve this?

Comment: Is this really impossible? Found several questions just like this with no answers :-(

Comment: I never was able to solve this. Used a few work around and changed the UI a little. Now i think using a module might be something that might achieve this, but I have not tested it out. So might be heading you in a wrong direction. Have you tried Angular's Slack or Gitter? Might be help there.

Comment: literally about 1 minute ago I think I solved this. Here's the thing - a router outlet doesn't need to exist BEFORE you navigate to the `'add-task/sales'` route. It kind of magically consumes the route even if you don't create it until later. So what you do is navigate to the outlet from your main app and THEN open the dialog containing `<router-outlet name="dialog-content"></router-outlet>` and it will magically appear. I tried tracing through the code but could never actually figure out why it wasn't matching, there's a lot of recursion and observables.

Comment: Yes it works :) even with a lazy route. Finally. I’ll try to post a real answer. I’m in angular 9 with ivy enabled (shouldn’t matter but good to know it works with it). Now I just need to figure out a ‘loading’ icon for it.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver damn dude... that's clever... thanks!

Comment: Note that as far as I can tell the named outlet must not be in a lazy module itself (not sure the *exact* constraint but that's the one I'm assuming). You can just make a skeleton dialog component containing nothing more than the router outlet. I'm not going to spend too much time making an answer below since your question only had 42 views in a year, but it does work :-)